# Advertising flag, “BR/EDR Not Supported.”, how is it interpreted?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

If the “BR/EDR Not Supported.” bit is set as "0" or "1" what does that mean? I have been confused for the last hour about how to interpret it.

If the bit is set as 1, does that mean the "BR/EDR Not Supported" is false which means that BR/EDR is indeed supported? Or is it the other way around with the bit set as "0"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is from [BLUETOOTH CORE SPECIFICATION Version 5.3 | Vol 3, Part C](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/):

> • For a device of the LE-only device type with all the following flags
> set as described:
>
> a) The ‘BR/EDR Not Supported’ flag to set one.
>
> b) The ‘Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Controller)’
> flag set to zero.

Having a `1` for the `BR/EDR Not Supported` flag means it does not support BR/EDR. i.e: it is an LE only device.